# How can I make a button with text and icon in different colors but same colors in hover state?

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I have an outline button that has an icon (fontawesome) and a text. The icon is green and the text is grey. I have achieved that. In its hover state, I need both the icon and text to turn white while the background turns green.  I'm having trouble achieving this because it is an outline button. My hover state applies border and background to the icon as well. (I'm using bootstrap 4).

This is what I need to achieve:
[image]

My code:

```css
.nh-round-secondary-btn {
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #717980;
}

.nh-round-secondary-btn i {
  color: #8abe57;
}

.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover,
.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover i {
  border: 2px solid #8abe57;
  background-color: #8abe57;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-9ZfPnbegQSumzaE7mks2IYgHoayLtuto3AS6ieArECeaR8nCfliJVuLh/GaQ1gyM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn nh-round-secondary-btn col-lg-5"><i class="fas fa-filter pr-2"></i>Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're dealing with specificity issues when selecting the elements. See the suggested edits below.

```css
.btn.nh-round-secondary-btn {
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #717980;
}

.btn.nh-round-secondary-btn i {
  color: #8abe57;
  transition: color .2s;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}
.btn.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover {
  border-color: #8abe57;
  background-color: #8abe57;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-9ZfPnbegQSumzaE7mks2IYgHoayLtuto3AS6ieArECeaR8nCfliJVuLh/GaQ1gyM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn nh-round-secondary-btn col-lg-5"><i class="fas fa-filter pr-2"></i>Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.nh-round-secondary-btn {
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #717980;
}

.nh-round-secondary-btn i {
  color: #8abe57;
}

.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover {
  background-color: #8abe57;
  color: #fff !important;
}
.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-9ZfPnbegQSumzaE7mks2IYgHoayLtuto3AS6ieArECeaR8nCfliJVuLh/GaQ1gyM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn nh-round-secondary-btn col-lg-5"><i class="fas fa-filter pr-2"></i>Text</button>
```

Comment: It better not to use `!important`. It is not necessarily in this case. Because, it will not work in this code anyway, because `<i>` have declared different color.

Answer (score 0):

### Why Does This Happen?

Your `:hover` state `color` is being overridden by another rule at the same specificity level from one of your imported CSS files. When two conflicting CSS rules are applied at the same specificity, CSS will choose the one that is applied *last*.

To be exact, it's the `.btn:hover` rule from bootstrap's `_buttons.scss:23`. You can make your rule apply by either increasing the specificity of your selector (as I've done in the below snippet by making the selector `.btn.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover`), or by using `!important` on the *rule* you want to forcibly increase the specificity on.

An alternative would be to make sure you import your CSS file after bootstrap, since CSS rules are evaluated in the order they are received, but I would recommend using higher specificity as it's more predictable.

---

### Additional Useful Links

- Here's a [Mozilla article on CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- Here's a [Specificity Calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/) so you can see exactly how different parts of a selector affect its specificity.

---

### Revised Snippet:

```css
.nh-round-secondary-btn {
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #717980;
}

.nh-round-secondary-btn i {
  color: #8abe57;
}

.btn.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover,
.nh-round-secondary-btn:hover i {
  border: 2px solid #8abe57;
  background-color: #8abe57;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-9ZfPnbegQSumzaE7mks2IYgHoayLtuto3AS6ieArECeaR8nCfliJVuLh/GaQ1gyM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn nh-round-secondary-btn col-lg-5"><i class="fas fa-filter pr-2"></i>Text</button>
```